# What is the contents of the cache after loop?

Tags: caching, memory, memory-management, architecture

A computer uses a small direct-mapped cache between the main memory and the
processor. The cache has four 16-bit words, and each word has an associated 13-bit tag,
as shown in Figure (a). When a miss occurs during a read operation, the requested
word is read from the main memory and sent to the processor. At the same time, it is
copied into the cache, and its block number is stored in the associated tag. Consider the
following loop in a program where all instructions and operands are 16 bits long:

```
LOOP: Add (R1)+,R0
      Decrement R2
      BNE     LOOP


<-13 bits-> <--16bit->
0|TAG     |DATA     |
2|        |         | 
4|        |         |
6|_______ | ______  |

(a)Cache
       .   
       .
    | A03C |<---ADDRESS 054E
    | 05D9 |    
    | 10D7 |
       .
       .

(b)Main Memory
```

Assume that, before this loop is entered, registers R0, R1, and R2 contain 0, 054E,
and 3, respectively. Also assume that the main memory contains the data shown in
Figure (b), where all entries are given in hexadecimal notation. The loop starts at
location LOOP = 02EC.
(a) Show the contents of the cache at the end of each pass through the loop.

Comment: the tag is of 13 bits and block offset is then 3 bits .But there is only 4 cache line .they are 0,2,4,6. Now the first memory location is 0000 0010 1110 1100 ,so add is goes to 4th block in cache . and operand is going to 6th block . But what will happen in the next instruction .where from it will start . if it is 02ED then it will be in the fifth block which is not present

Comment: Is this a homework assignment, or are you asking this question in order to solve some other practical problem?

Comment: Not a homework question.Trying to understand what is the best replacement strategy and the memory state ..@Anderson